Dynamically Import & Parse JSON Files Within a URI `File` Scheme - Serverless Environment
This problem that I'm facing is very unique to me and I hope it may not be to you. Essentially, I am working on a React project built with CRA and it won't/can't be hosted on a server. The goal of the app is to read JSON files, parse their content, and conduct further processing of that data in the UI. However, since the app will be in a serverless/network-less environment (file:///), I'll need to read and interpret these files in runtime.
These files will be subject to user configuration (not from the UI) - meaning they will have access to the JSON files, have the ability to modify them, add or remove JSON files, and then expect to see the resulting output in the React app (index.html at that point). Since these files (and the amount of these files) are subject to change, I cannot statically import them. Furthermore, since this app will be in a serverless environment, I can't use the Fetch API either.
I've placed these files within the public/ folder outside the src/ folder - since these JSON files can be expected to change at any frequency for user-configuration needs, they can't be part of the build process. Therefore, they can't be inside the src folder.
So far, I've been able to access files with the dynamic import() function, with the following code in development-mode only (localhost):
myJson= await import(`/public/my-jsons/${fileName}`)

However, the following doesn't work in a production build:
myJson= await import(`/my-jsons/${fileName}`)

In fact, I can't even run an npm run build command because I get this error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/my-jsons'

I'm beginning to wonder if this is even possible. I believe it should be, but it's just something that I am failing to understand regarding .tsconfig or webpack rules. I've asked ChatGPT for insight on my problem and this is what it has said:

JSON Files in public: Placing JSON files in public is fine for serving static assets and accessing them via HTTP requests.


Dynamic Imports: For dynamic imports, JSON files need to be in the src directory so that Webpack processes them as modules.

I'm not sure why webpack can't just treat JSON files the same way it'd treat other static files? Especially if JSON is sometimes read/parsed in runtime (i.e. JSON.parse()).
Is this use-case actually impossible given the constraints? Am I misunderstanding anything regarding tsconfig.json or CRA? If it is possible, what steps can I take for this to fully work? Thanks in advance for your help and for your time :) .
My project's folder structure is like so:
my-project:
└───public
|     └───my-jsons
|         └───sample1.json
|         └───sample2.json
└───src
    └───components
etc.

When built, this is what it looks like:
build:
└───my-jsons
    └───sample1.json
    └───sample2.json
└───index.html
etc.


If it helps, these are the contents within my tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
  },
  "include": ["src", "public"]
}

Edit:
Ideally, we'd want to stray away from any user-gestures. Meaning we wouldn't want to have a dialog open for the user to select which files they'd want to open. I have written a drag-n-drop feature, but that's only serving as an alternative for the moment. The functionality we're striving for is to point to a distinct folder holding our JSON (the JSON can't be part of our src/ folder) and parse that JSON. The idea is that a user can click on <a></a> tag pointing to the JSON location (the number of these JSON files can change), then that JSON will be interpreted and rendered in real-time through React components. So far I have a bit of this working, but only in development mode (I suppose since the file URI schema isn't used). Here is a doodle of the idea:

As I'm learning a bit more about File access through the browser, I'm realizing that perhaps the ideal we're striving for might not be feasible. The fact that I can't statically import JSON before run-time or that I can't just do an HTTP request for this information makes it tricky. If there is no way to veer away from user-gestures, then I'll need to justify the use of user-gestures to my team. Thanks again for your help!

"the app will be in a serverless/network-less environment": What is the scheme of the URL that will be used to access the built SPA?

@jsejcksn so far we have hash-encoding to 'navigate' between JSON renderings. I.e.: file:///C:/user/username/my-project-ui/build/index.html#/sample-json/1 .

^ In that case: you won't be able to make network requests to file: URLs because they're restricted by CORS (this includes fetch, import, etc.).

^ The only remaining option is to use the File System API. That topic has been covered extensively by other questions (one example: How to recursively read local files and directories in web browser using File System Access API) — see the tag [tag:file-system-access-api].

This question is similar to: Is there a way to programmatically set the default directory with File System Access API. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Thanks @jsejcksn for sharing these. However, it seems that these options require user-gestures. Ideally, I wanted the program to read/import JSON from a list of file paths at run-time without any user-gestures. But as you mentioned since the scheme this would be running in is file, I will face CORs issues.

^ @GioR. Attempting to access a resource on a user's file system from a browser without user-activation will never be possible without a cooperating process running on that device (e.g. http server). This is by design to protect the user.

@jsejcksn the way I've been going about it, yes, its looking impossible. However I've found someone here that has managed to load files via <iframe> tags.  It seems a bit hacky, but it's working so far within our file URI-based approach.
